# How do I avoid artifacts/blurring when enlarging an image in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, image

I want to show [this image](http://i.gyazo.com/18b227adb4c442b09152ca6ebc04c54c.png) in an Android (Java) app, but the app displays it as. How do I display the first image in an app without getting this blurring effect?

EDIT::

And how can I change the size with no blurring effect?, the imagen will show pixelated. Like this http://i.gyazo.com/18b227adb4c442b09152ca6ebc04c54c.png

Answer (score 2):

To show image with the original size use layout_width="wrap_content" and layout_height="wrap_content". This is considering that your image is smaller than the screen in which it is to be shown. Also if you only provide image in your drawable-hdpi folder then the images in mdpi screen with be scaled by a predefined scale factor(possibly 2). Same case applies for other screen density. To avoid this scaling you can put your images in drawable-nodpi folder.

Note: the images you posted are not properly made(highly pixilated). Try optimizing the resolution and provide multiple resources.

Comment: Correct with `drawable-nodpi`, but use `CENTER_INSIDE` to scale the image in the ImageView, and `wrap_content` becomes unnecessary. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html#CENTER_INSIDE